# Get domain name in url with JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, url, jstl, el

I am trying to get the domain name from the url with JSTL. The 2 methods I know return the wrong information. I need exactly what is in the URL.

When I do:

```
${pageContext.request.remoteHost}
```

I get my server's IP.

When I do:

```
${pageContext.request.serverName}
```

I normally get the right domain name, but on a server we have on amazon its returning "server1" instead of the correct domain name, probably because of the way it handles multiple domains.

Anyone know how I can get the current domain name in the URL?

I may need to get the URL and then parse it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestUrl()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) to:

> Reconstructs the URL the client used to make the request. The returned URL contains a protocol, server name, port number, and server path, but it does not include query string parameters.

this would return a String like [Get domain name in url with JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806045/get-domain-name-in-url-with-jstl)

It should then be trivial to parse this to find the string that comes after [the scheme](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getScheme()) (http, https, etc) and before [the requestURI](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI()).

Answer (score 14):

You should be using [`ServletRequest#getLocalName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalName%28%29) instead. It returns the real hostname of the server. The [`ServletRequest#getServerName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29) indeed returns the value as set in `Host` header.

```
${pageContext.request.localName}
```

That's all. The solutions suggested in other answers are plain clumsy and hacky.

---

By the way, the [`ServletRequest#getRemoteHost()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost%28%29) doesn't return the server's hostname, but the client's one (or the IP when the hostname is not immediately resolveable). It's obviously the same as the server's one whenever you run both the webserver and webbrowser at physically the same machine. If you're interested in the server's IP, use [`ServletRequest#getLocalAddr()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalAddr%28%29). The terms "local" and "remote" must be interpreted from server's perspective, not from the client's. It's after all the server there where all that Java code runs.

Comment: localName returns 127.0.0.1 here. The reason seems to be that I use a web server as passthrough proxy to jetty.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse domain name from URL

**OR**

```
 public static String getDomainName(String url)
    {
         URL u;
         try {
             u = new URL(url);
         } 
         catch (Exception e) { 
             return "";
         }
         return u.getHost();
    }
```

Comment: Okay, that's what I need to know how to do. I might need better explain my question. How do I get the url, and parse it?

Answer (score -3):

${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Comment: Context path is not host name.

Comment: .. it is the name of the webapp/current context